# Cannot find the fault in my JAVASCRIPT number guessing game

Tags: javascript, while-loop, infinite-loop, liveserver

I created a small number guessing game in JAVASCRIPT but the program only runs correctly if I get the answer right on the first attempt, if I get it right on any other attempt then it just stops prompting me and the page loads infinitely till it reaches an error, even though I do not see any infinite loop situation in my code. Basically, It should stop loading once I guessed the number right , but again, it only does this if I get it correctly on the first try (btw I am using VS code Live Server so I am suspecting something might be off with it). Would really appreciate if someone can find any faults:

```js
let maximum = parseInt(prompt("Enter a maximum number"));
const targetNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * maximum) + 1);

while (!maximum) {
  maximum = parseInt(prompt("Enter a valid number"))
}
console.log(targetNum);

let guess = parseInt(prompt("Enter your first guess"));
let attempts = 1;
while (guess !== targetNum) {
  console.log(new Date());
  attempts++;
  if (guess > targetNum) {
    guess = prompt("TOO HIGH! Try again")
  } else if (guess < targetNum) {
    guess = prompt("TOO LOW! Try again")
  }
}
console.log(`You got it! it took you ${attempts} attempts`);
```

Comment: `the page loads infinitely` can't see why - does `console.log(targetNum);` ever get output?

Answer (score 0):

You could also simplify your code by changing `while (guess !== targetNum) { ... }` to `while (guess != targetNum) { ... }`, as this comparison would do the type conversion implicitly for you. (Write less - do more ;-)).